# Getting a tooltip when pasting text in safari

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, tooltip, clipboard

I am using the same code from this page https://web.dev/patterns/clipboard/paste-text/ and when pressing it renders tooltip in safari and user has to press tooltip in order to paste text. And it does not work at all in Firefox. Is there any way of solving it ?

```js
const pasteButton = document.querySelector('#paste-btn');

pasteButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
   try {
     const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText()
     document.querySelector('textarea').value += text;
     console.log('Text pasted.');
   } catch (error) {
     console.log('Failed to read clipboard. Using execCommand instead.');
     document.querySelector('textarea').focus();
     const result = document.execCommand('paste')
     console.log('document.execCommand result: ', result);
   }
});
```

```css
#paste-btn {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="paste-btn">Paste</button>
<textarea rows="5" cols="60"></textarea>
```

Comment: I added the JS code from the website and converted it into a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

With modern browser security, access to the clipboard is finnicky. There have always been some form of restriction on clipboard access in a browser.

The user will probably receive an error like:

> DOMException: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document.

Typically the website will ask the user if they want the website to access the clipboard. On Chrome, this is a popup by the lock icon in the Omnibar.

[image: Share clipboard Chrome dialog]

The `await navigator.clipboard.readText()` should work fine in Safari version 13.1+, but it will not work at all in Firefox. You can check the compatibility here: [MDN: Clipboard: readText() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText#browser_compatibility)

This guide may also help you out: [*"Unblocking clipboard access"*](https://web.dev/async-clipboard/) – *web.dev*

Comment: it does work in safari, but after pressing paste button you will see safari's tooltip(kind of like prompt that freezes UI)